# How to go one view controller to another view controller when we login with social networks in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new for Ios and in my app i am trying to move one view controller to another view controller when we login with social networks as like twitter for this i have already registered my app with twitter

According to my code when we tapped on twitter login button then twitter login page will be loaded on screen and there is "AuthorizedApp" button is available on twitter login page when we click on that button we get user details

After we get that user details i want move another page

Note:-

My main intention is when we clicked on that "AuthorizedApp" button then i want to  move another page please help me some one

According to my code i am getting exception like:-  Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

### My code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()<FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" andSecret:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];

    //google plus login button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(loginOAuth)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 390, 300, 30);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CALayer * d = [button layer];
    [d setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [d setCornerRadius:20];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)loginOAuth {

    UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen failure!!!");
        NSLog(@"User name ---->>>%@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername);
        NSLog(@"User id ------> %@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID);
        [self movetoanotherview];
    }];
    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) movetoanotherview{

     ViewController1 *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    [dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So far so good! What is your question? Is it not working? In what way? Crash, nothing happens, unwanted behaviour!?

Comment: not working it's not moving to another view

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you're creating a view controller in a block. The view controller will be gone together with the block at the end of it's scope.

Try to declare dvc as a property inside your .h file (or at the top of your .m file)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController1 *dvc;
Then do this instead:
self.dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
[_dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:_dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Try to present it from loginViewController